Python CNN/RNN image feature size, error constantly cycles between 4d-3d-2d-1d
Im doing a CNN/RNN image captioning model and im currently facing an issue with the tensor shape during inference.
CNNEncoder:
class CNNEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_size):
        super(CNNEncoder, self).__init__()
        resnet = models.resnet50(weights=models.ResNet50_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1)
        modules = list(resnet.children())[:-1]
        self.resnet = nn.Sequential(*modules)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(resnet.fc.in_features, embed_size)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(embed_size, momentum=0.01)
    
    def forward(self, images):
        with torch.no_grad():
            features = self.resnet(images).squeeze()
        features = self.bn(self.linear(features))
        return features

During training, it works:
def train(encoder,decoder, device, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs):

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for i, (images, captions, lengths) in enumerate(data_loader):
            images = images.to(device)
            captions = captions.to(device)
            print(images.shape)
            
            # Forward pass
            features = encoder(images)

output: torch.Size([16, 3, 224, 224])

Load image class:
def load_image(img_path):
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])
    image = Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB")
    image = transform(image).unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch dimension
    return image

However, during inference, even if i supply the encoder with the same image size, i still get an error
Generate captions function:
def generate_captions(device, encoder, decoder, vocabulary, img_path, max_length=20):
    result = []
    encoder.eval()
    decoder.eval()

    with torch.inference_mode():
        # Load and prepare the image
        image = load_image(img_path).to(device)  # Should return (1, 3, 224, 224)
        
        print(image.shape) 
        # Forward pass through encoder
        feature = encoder(image)  # Should return (1, embed_size)

Error if i unsqueeze the image:
output: torch.Size([1, 3, 224, 224])

File ~\anaconda3\envs\cuda_test\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\batchnorm.py:341, in BatchNorm1d._check_input_dim(self, input)
    339 def _check_input_dim(self, input):
    340     if input.dim() != 2 and input.dim() != 3:
--> 341         raise ValueError(f"expected 2D or 3D input (got {input.dim()}D input)")

ValueError: expected 2D or 3D input (got 1D input)

Even if i do not squeeze the image during using load_image function it will still prompt:
File ~\anaconda3\envs\cuda_test\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\batchnorm.py:452, in BatchNorm2d._check_input_dim(self, input)
    450 def _check_input_dim(self, input):
    451     if input.dim() != 4:
--> 452         raise ValueError(f"expected 4D input (got {input.dim()}D input)")

ValueError: expected 4D input (got 3D input)

Squeezing or unsqueezing the image tensor doesnt even work, what the heck is going on?
I tried squeezing and unsqueezing the image tensor but the errors are just cycling back and forth, telling me it needs to be a 4D input so i unsqueeze it. Then it tells me that it needs to be a 2D or 3D input (got 1D input)?

Seems like your n_samples dim is still missing. Try .shape and .reshape to see what is there and potentially expand it. The training was using n_samples as the first dim, so even if you are inferencing only one image, it still needs to have n_samples=1.

@JakubVonšovský
image.shape gives it [1,3,244,244] which is a 4d input after unsqueezing so the dimension is still there but the encoder is recognizing it as a 1D input
